# How to pass password to scp?

Tags: linux, scp, io-redirection

I know it is not recommended, but is it at all possible to pass the user's password to scp?

I'd like to copy a file via scp as part of a batch job and the receiving server does, of course, need a password and, no, I cannot easily change that to key-based authentication.

Comment: See also (later) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462284/how-to-respond-to-password-prompt-when-using-scp-in-a-shell-script where one answer mentions another possible way to do this.  (NB: this is not a duplicate question - it is the original which the other duplicates.)

Comment: _Very_ closely related: [Pass a password to ssh in pure bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454037/pass-a-password-to-ssh-in-pure-bash/24455773#24455773)

Comment: Instead of login via scp and copy, you can first setup a master connection with ssh, then run scp to copy the file via the master connection, without password. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2869/17823

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can script it with a tool like [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) (there are handy bindings too, like [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) for Python).

Comment: Link to http://expect.nist.gov/ is broken. Maybe this?: http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Comment: sudo apt-get install expect

Comment: >> brew info sshpass

Error: No available formula with the name "sshpass" 
We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security.

;)

Answer (score 753):

Use [sshpass](http://sshpass.sourceforge.net/):

```
sshpass -p "password" scp -r user@example.com:/some/remote/path /some/local/path
```

or so the password does not show in the bash history

```
sshpass -f "/path/to/passwordfile" scp -r user@example.com:/some/remote/path /some/local/path
```

The above copies contents of path from the remote host to your local.

**Install :**

- ubuntu/debian

  - `apt install sshpass`
- centos/fedora

  - `yum install sshpass`
- mac w/ macports

  - `port install sshpass`
- mac w/ brew

  - `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb`

Comment: This recently saved me a lot of trouble on a project, thanks :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 it only worked for me with single quotes over the password (e.g. 'password' instead of "password").

Comment: @odedfos, yes you need to use single quotes because some password generated chars can have a special interpretation in double quoted string interpolation

Comment: This is how you install sshpass `apt-get install sshpass`

Comment: On CentOS it's `yum -y install sshpass`

Comment: `sudo port install sshpass` if you have [macports](https://www.macports.org/) on a mac

Comment: The most secure way to do this is with a password *file*, like this: `sshpass -f `passwdfile` scp [...]`. This way, the password won't show up in `ps` listings, etc. and you can protect the password with file permissions.

Comment: On OSX `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb`

Comment: `scp` shows progress when not using `sshpass`. Is it possible to get that back?

Comment: Best answer: note it also works with ssh (`sshpass -p pass ssh 'command'`)

Comment: It works, but the console output from `scp` is hidden.

Comment: The url for macOS has changed to: brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb

Comment: On Debian didn't work for me with `-f "filename"` until I removed quotes around the file name, i.e.: `sshpass -f /path/to/passwordfile scp -r user@example.com:/some/remote/path /some/local/path`

Comment: In case if you observe a strict host key check error then you can add -o with `StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` options. The complete example is as follows  `sshpass -p "password" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@domain-name.com:/tmp/from/psoutput /tmp/to/psoutput`

Comment: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb` no longer works @jbaums > Error: Non-checksummed download of sshpass formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported! `brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.

Answer (score 72):

just generate a ssh key like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

copy the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
and lastly add it to the remote machines `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

make sure remote machine have the permissions `0700 for ~./ssh folder` and `0600 for ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: As I wrote: No, I cannot easily switch to key-based authentication.

Comment: Do you mean .authorized_keys rather than . authorization_keys?

Comment: A valid use for this would be a bash script that does multiple scp/ssh calls to a server where you want to ask the user for the password for the remote server.  The password will then not show in history and you still have the befit of challenging for the password... but only once.  I don't want to use a key file because I want to still authenticate the script user.

Comment: Another valid use would be if you cannot easily enable key-based authentication on the target. Example: One of the main NAS producers - Synology with their DSM 6.0 - does not support it even in 2016. Sure, you could mess with configuration files and hope an update won't just overwrite it again (updating DSM frequently does break custom modifications). 

Sometimes - especially when the OP expressly writes they're already aware it's not optimal - people just need a solution.

Comment: You should use `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <remote_server>` to copy the key on the remote server

Comment: @RousseauAlexandre  do you mean "onto" or "to" the remove server? This answer is shocking, should it not be your_user@server ?

Comment: @mckenzm `ssh-copy-id` copy the public key from your local to the server. You should try `man ssh-copy-id` to get more information about this command.

Comment: apologies, I mixed my comments. I did not mean to say your comment was shocking, I should have separated these to show the answer above it was surprising.

Comment: Come on, anyone can find out how to generate SSH keys, the question is obviously not about that. Not everyone has complete control over every computer that they connect to.

Comment: This doesn't work for remote machines which are embedded Linux devices which have read-only file-systems, since you can't write anything to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target device.

Comment: ssh-keygen will generate two files: id_rsa.pub,id_rsa. then put id_rsa.pub to remote server [USER]/.ssh/ and rename it to authorized_keys or just copy the content of id_rsa.pub in to authorized_keys on the remote server.  and at the client, use the scp's "i" option to specify the id_rsa file. then you can use scp without to input the password

Answer (score 61):

If you are connecting to the server from Windows, the Putty version of scp ("pscp") lets you pass the password with the `-pw` parameter.

[This is mentioned in the documentation here.](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp)

Comment: Show an example, please.

Comment: Also, might want to add C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY to your path to use these commands.

Comment: @SDsolar here's a syntax example: `pscp -pw 'MyPa$$word' username@servername:/somedir/somefile ~/somedest` (I hate using putty like this, but it works)

Comment: @geneorama password worked for me but only without the single quotations.. thanks..

Answer (score 53):

curl can be used as a alternative to scp to copy a file and it supports a password on the commandline.

```
curl --insecure --user username:password -T /path/to/sourcefile sftp://desthost/path/
```

Comment: It quite slower than 'scp' but it does the job fine.

Comment: I found this to be faster when the destination is configured with a huge password prompt delay.  `scp` has to wait 30+ seconds to let me put in a password, but `curl` worked immediately.

Comment: @Ghost8472 configured yes, but sometimes this delay is resolving the hostname, and also happens for sftp.

Comment: I got "curl: (1) Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl"

Comment: I got an error saying that curl doesn't recognize -T as a parameter.

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'T' is ambiguous. Possible matches
include: -TimeoutSec -TransferEncoding.
At line:1 char:40
+ curl --insecure --user andres:notmypassword -T nottheserver:/home/andr ...
+                                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: @AndrésMarafioti look like you call Invoke-WebRequest from powershell this can does not work the same as curl. To my knowledge is does not support sftp or uploads

Comment: The curl method, above, works when shell access is not allowed on the account. e.g. "Shell access is not enabled on your account!"

Answer (score 24):

You can use the 'expect' script on unix/terminal

For example create  'test.exp' :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
        spawn scp  /usr/bin/file.txt root@<ServerLocation>:/home
        set pass "Your_Password"
        expect {
        password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
                  }
```

run the script

```
expect test.exp
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Prerequisite:   sudo apt-get install expect

Answer (score 11):

You may use `ssh-copy-id` to add ssh key:

```
$which ssh-copy-id #check whether it exists
```

If exists:

```
ssh-copy-id  "user@remote-system"
```

Comment: Superb.  Simple, works, and no 3rd-party packages or ssh-keygen setup required.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example of how you do it with `expect` tool:

```perl
sub copyover {
    $scp = Expect->spawn("/usr/bin/scp ${srcpath}/$file $who:${destpath}/$file");
    $scp->expect(30,"ssword: ") || die "Never got password prompt from $dest:$!\n";
    print $scp 'password' . "\n";
    $scp->expect(30,"-re",'$\s') || die "Never got prompt from parent system:$!\n";
    $scp->soft_close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is in perl, sorry i didn't write that. (5 years ago :) )

Answer (score 6):

Nobody mentioned it, but [Putty scp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (pscp) has a -pw option for password.

Documentation can be found here:  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp

Comment: It was mentioned in [user524607's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4310068/1491895) 5 years ago.

Comment: Found it, and am adding C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY to my path.

Comment: Under WINE ?  on Windows use plink.   BTW people putty-tools is a package.

Answer (score 3):

Once you set up `ssh-keygen` as explained above, you can do

`scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/`

If you want to lessen typing each time, you can modify your `.bash_profile` file and put

```
alias remote_scp='scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/
```

Then from your terminal do `source ~/.bash_profile`. Afterwards if you type `remote_scp` in your terminal it should run the `scp` command without password.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a poor man's Linux/Python/Expect-like example based on this blog post: [Upgrading simple shells to fully interactive 
TTYs](https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/#method1pythonptymodule). I needed this for old machines where I can't install Expect or add modules to Python.

Code:

```
(
    echo 'scp jmudd@mysite.com:./install.sh .'
    sleep 5
    echo 'scp-passwd'
    sleep 5
    echo 'exit'
) |

python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/usr/bin/bash")'
```

Output:

```
scp jmudd@mysite.com:install.sh .
bash-4.2$ scp jmudd@mysite.com:install.sh .
Password: 
install.sh                                 100%   15KB 236.2KB/s   00:00    
bash-4.2$ exit
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure password authentication is enabled on the target server. If it runs Ubuntu, then open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, find lines `PasswordAuthentication=no` and comment all them out (put `#` at the start of the line), save the file and run `sudo systemctl restart ssh` to apply the configuration. If there is no such line then you're done.
2. Add `-o PreferredAuthentications="password"` to your `scp` command, e.g.:

   ```sh
   scp -o PreferredAuthentications="password" /path/to/file user@server:/destination/directory
   ```

Comment: How do you indicate the actual password though?

Comment: @Osmar You'll be prompted for password when you run the command

Comment: What is the point? The question was ```How to pass password to scp?``` that means (I think) I don't want to type it.

Comment: @MagnoC, the point was to switch `scp` to a password-based authentication

Comment: @Finesse ok but the O.P. needs to not type password. I think ```scp``` is already password-based as it always ask for it in default installation. He (as me) needs to do some automated process (an ETL maybe) that needs to call ```scp``` without user interactivity. That's my interpretation of this question. What actually solved my problem was ```/usr/bin/sshpass -p "$6" scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -r $7@$5:$8 $9``` inside a shell script that is called from inside a Java program responsible to ask the password from a WEB browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have "expect" tool before, if not, do it

   `# apt-get install expect`
2. create the a script file with following content. (# vi /root/scriptfile)

   `spawn scp /path_from/file_name user_name_here@to_host_name:/path_to`

   `expect "password:"`

   `send put_password_here\n;`

   `interact`
3. execute the script file with "expect" tool

   `# expect /root/scriptfile`

Answer (score 0):

copy files from one server to other server ( on scripts)

Install putty on ubuntu or other Linux machines. putty comes with pscp. we can copy files with pscp.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install putty 
echo n |  pscp -pw "Password@1234" -r user_name@source_server_IP:/copy_file_path/files /path_to_copy/files
```

For more options see pscp help.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with powershell and Posh-SSH. Powershell core should be supported

```
Import-Module "C:\tmp\Posh-SSH\3.0.8\Posh-SSH.psd1" # https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/releases

# Connect with pubkey authentication, providing the Passphrase non-interactive, and accepting any remote pubkey
$sftpSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName example.com -Credential $keyFilePassphrase -KeyFile "C:\Path\To\private_key" -AcceptKey

# Write file to remote
Set-SFTPItem -SessionId $sftpSession.SessionID -Path C:\tmp\test.txt -Destination "/home/user/"
```

---

You could also use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn scp user@host:/source user@host2:/target
expect "password"
send -- "$PASSWORD\n"
interact
```

Install expect and run the script

```
sudo apt install expect -y
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/update-file.exp
/usr/local/bin/update-file.exp
```

Answer (score -1):

Since not using key based auth isn't in the title, the following steps will help users who can switch to key based auth.  It skips passwords for scp and ssh.

Copy your ssh public key to the server (careful about not overwriting authorized keys)

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remoteIP:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Change the permissions:

```
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

Follow a guide like this for more details:
https://idratherbewriting.com/jekylldoctheme-separate-outputs/mydoc/mydoc_no_password_prompts_scp.html

Answer (score -2):

In case if you observe a strict host key check error then use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` options.

The complete example is as follows
`sshpass -p "password" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@domain-name.com:/tmp/from/psoutput /tmp/to/psoutput`

Answer (score -2):

You can use below steps. This works for me!

**Step1-**
create a normal file suppose "**fileWithScpPassword**" which contains the ssh password for the destination server.

**Step2-** use **sshpaas -f** followed by password file name and then normal scp command.

**sshpass -f "fileWithScpPassword" scp  /filePathToUpload user@ip:/destinationPath/**

Answer (score -2):

One easy way I do this:

Use the same scp cmd as you use with ssh keys i.e

`scp -C -i <path_to opens sshkey> <'local file_path'> user@<ip_address_VM>: <'remote file_path’>`

for transferring file from local to remote

but instead of providing the correct <path_to_opensshkey>, use some garbage path. Due to wrong key path you will be asked for password instead and you can simply pass the password now to get the work done!

Comment: Jeez.... I can't believe. Why one don't simply call scp and type the password as any normal person? The O.P. don't want to type the password.

Comment: @MagnoC your typed password remains in the shell history

Comment: Despite this ... the O.P. don't want to type the password. He wants to pass it using some automated process. So your ```you will be asked for password instead``` is not useful here.

Answer (score -3):

An alternative would be add the public half of the user's key to the authorized-keys file on the target system. On the system you are initiating the transfer from, you can run an ssh-agent daemon and add the private half of the key to the agent. The batch job can then be configured to use the agent to get the private key, rather than prompting for the key's password.

This should be do-able on either a UNIX/Linux system or on Windows platform using pageant and pscp.

Comment: The question said he can't use key-based authentication.

Comment: Also, if it were me, I assume I can't alter the other server - all I want is to copy a file.

Answer (score -6):

All the solutions mentioned above can work only if you the app installed or you should have the admin rights to install except or sshpass.

I found this very useful link to simply start the scp in Background.

```
$ nohup scp file_to_copy user@server:/path/to/copy/the/file > nohup.out 2>&1
```

https://charmyin.github.io/scp/2014/10/07/run-scp-in-background/

Comment: How would running the scp in the background input the password??

Answer (score -11):

I found this really helpful answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44059/progress-bar-in-scp-command).

```
rsync -r -v --progress -e ssh user@remote-system:/address/to/remote/file /home/user/
```

Not only you can pass there the password, but also it will show the progress bar when copying. Really awesome.

Comment: and how exactly are you providing password here?