# How to respond to password prompt when using SCP in a shell script?

Tags: shell, passwords, scp, prompt, keyboard-events

First of all, I am well aware of that there are many of questions regarding this topic. I have read them, but still could figure out an appropriate answer for my situation.

I would like to `scp` the entire `~/cs###/assign1` dir from local to school home dir with a shell script. My question is, is there a way in my script to wait for the password prompt, and then simulate key board event to 'type' in my password?

---

[here](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/) is a really detailed guide of how to set up the key

Comment: This question sounds exactly like your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp

Comment: Note that the answers to the putative duplicate question do not mention 'ssh keys' as is mentioned by BZ.

Comment: I was hoping that there could be a solution using only simple shell or unix commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)

Comment: The link in "here" is invalid as of today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are ssh keys not allowed? That would be a better solution.

Comment: NO, because that is not in the scope of the question.  There are reasons these questions are asked.  "Run command" in Azure, say.  It may not be your box.

Answer (score 17):

Use "sshpass"!

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "password" scp -r /some/local/path user@example.com:/some/remote/path
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can easily do that. What you *can* do is using public key authentication instead.

Something along these lines

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh school mkdir .ssh/
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh school "cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(or `dsa`).

But hey, it's not serverfault, is it? ;-)

Comment: The server and everything was setup by school, I have no control of the setting at that end

Comment: These settings are in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using keys, or an external library.

I don't think it's possible otherwise (I hope I'm not wrong), as it imposes automatic brute force intrusion and sniffing of passwords.

There are libraries that can do what you want (use the SFTP protocol, not calling scp), such as [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/).

Again, I highly recommend keys.

Comment: C'mon, automating brute force attacks can be done using libraries as well ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you should use keys. But [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) can automate the interactive aspect of the process IF you want to hardcode your password in a plain-text script file.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this - http://code.google.com/p/enchanter/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which platform you are using at home and at school.  Assuming Linux, Cygwin or OS/X you have several options:

1. Public key authentication if it
   hasn't been turned off at the server
2. ssh-agent and ssh-add to enter your password once per session

For option (1), you would

1. generate a keypair at home using
   ssh-keygen, with no passphrase on
   the private key. Note that omitting a passphrase is probably not a good idea if other people use the same computer, but your objective was to get around having to type in the password.
2. upload the PUBLIC key to your school
   account and place it in
   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. Use scp with the "-i identityfile"
   option, where identityfile is the
   full path to your private key.  Or, add an entry to .ssh/config (see the man pages)

For the second option, ssh-agent allows you to cache your password in a local process one time per session.  You set an expiration time

Comment: Of multiple solutions in multiple answers, this is the only one worked for me. Copied the contents of my `id_rsa.pub` file to the remote's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` directory and now I can `scp -i` and no manual password is required!

Comment: And as a side bonus - no manual password is required for the `ssh` sessions as well (which is kind'a the same thing, but was a nice surprise). When logging in to a remote machine multiple times a day, this is a time saver.

Comment: I just found out that `scp` works w/o the need for the `-i identityfile`. Looks like ssh takes care of the key matching once both sides are configured correctly. I guess ssh looks at the local `~/.ssh` directory for `id_rsa.pub` by default??

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount the directory from a Windows machine (e.g. via AFS, NFS or SMB which my university's Windows labs all did), you can use [pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) with the -pw switch.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up `ssh-keygen` as explained [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216499537-How-to-configure-passwordless-login-in-Mac-OS-X-and-Linux), you can do

`scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/`

where `id_rsa` is the local key generated in the `ssh-keygen` setup.

If you want to lessen typing each time, you can modify your `.bash_profile` file and put

```
alias remote_scp='scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /local/path/to/file remote@ip.com:/path/in/remote/server/
```

Then from your terminal do `source ~/.bash_profile`. Afterwards if you type `remote_scp` in your terminal it should run the `scp` command without password.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to do this on our systems automatically - I ssh into one device, and then ssh to the next device, and on both, I cannot install any other software.  So I can only use existing shell script commands.  I can either copy all the files of a type with, such as *.png, or one by one in my script file, having to enter the password for each individual file.  The one thing I did that was helpful was to type the password into a file, cut it, and be able to paste it to each prompt for each file.

Answer (score -1):

As many have already said that using ssh keys would be the safest and best way.
If anyone else is still wondering around and searching for help, in Ubuntu help there is a fast and straight forward [way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) to use ssh keys.

Comment: unfortunately that sort of change would require approval in most shops.  We need to understand that the question is asked because these options are not available.