# how to execute a scp command with the user name and password in one line

Tags: terminal, command, scp

I would like to put the password in on one line when running scp in my terminal

`scp user1@xxx.xxx.x.5:sys_config /var/www/dev/`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/50096/476681

Answer (score 32):

Thanks for your feed back got it to work I used the sshpass tool.

`sshpass -p 'password' scp user1@xxx.xxx.x.5:sys_config /var/www/dev/`

Comment: whether sshpass is a well-known Linux cmd?
Because it's not working for me, do I need to install any packages for that?

Comment: @kshitijchaurasiya - A simple 'apt-get install sshpass' should do it.

Answer (score -5):

Using sshpass works best. 
To just include your password in scp use the ' ':

```
scp user1:'password'@xxx.xxx.x.5:sys_config /var/www/dev/
```

Comment: Does this even conform to scp command line syntax?  It thinks user1 is the host.

Comment: This does not work, you can't pass password like that. You should use sshpass or expect.