# Postgres :script to copy schema from internal server to deployment server ; without entering passwords at every step

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ubuntu, passwords, dbmigrate

I want to copy my database schema (just schema ;not data) from internal server  to external server. 
The problem I am facing is entering passwords at every step. Even though the steps to copy are pretty simple, I am not able to generate a script to automate teh whole process.

What I have till now:

on internal server:

```
pg_dump -C -s --file=schema.txt {name}
scp schema.txt prakhar@{external server}:/home/prakhar
```

on external server:

```
dropdb {name}
createdb {name}
psql --file=schema.txt {name}
```

At each step I am prompted for password. 
I want to do two things: 
  1: Run the script from external server to fetch schema from internal ; or the other way around
  2: Incorporate the password for both internal and external servers in a way the the script takes care of it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping those commands in *bash* scripts, and in each one, prior to running the commands, add the following line:

```
export PGPASSWORD=<password>
```

Where  is the password you want to use. This will export it as an environment variable which is available to the *Postgres* commands.

Here are [other methods](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt), including *PGPASSWORD*, to specify the *Postgres* password.

For *nix commands like *scp*, there are other options. One is [sshpass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp). That would work well if you wanted to keep this all as a shell script.

Another option, and the one I would probably use for this sort of thing, would be to scrap the shell script wrapper and instead use something like *Python*'s [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/en/latest/).

You can run commands using *sudo*, as well as commands on remote machines, as well as shell commands like the *Postgres* utility programs (you would want to set *PGPASSWORD* in the environment hash within *Fabric* for that).