# Script to automate building process

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, makefile, ssh-keys

I'm working on some legacy software and need to build manually every time. How can I automate the following steps within a shell script?:

```
clearmake clean
clearmake
clearmake package
scp /path/to/package user@remotehost:path
password:
```

Also, how to make clearmake faster? Should I change the type of encryption on the remote host or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What you want automate over the `bash mymake`.? (the `mymake` is the above script). Maybe `chmod 755 mymake` and `./mymake`? Use the [ssh-keygen](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) to allow you using ssh without entering passwords every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate a series of commands with a script, you can place the commands in a text file. This file can be given execute privileges with the chmod command. If the problem is that your scp command needs to pass a password. Look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)

Comment: expect solved  this issue, thanks. Also, commands over ssh are passed as arguments. "  ssh user@host 'cmd 1; cmd2'  ".