# Bash script automation : Involve copying file from source to dest, executing script in destination and copy result from dest to surce

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement to create an automation script which will do the below stuff in given order :

1. Copy some script & XML from source to destination.
2. Run the script in the destination
3. Copy the results (which are files) from the destination to source.

I am using "expect" to copy files from source to destination. Then I am trying to establish ssh connection towards the destination and execute script in the destination. Once we have result generated, I will again copy files using "expect" but this time from destination to source.

I was wondering if there is any better way of doing the same.

Code to copy the files using "expect" as I need to pass password for scp :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set from [lindex $argv 0]
set to [lindex $argv 1]
set pass [lindex $argv 2]
puts "$from, $to and $pass ."
# connect via scp
spawn sudo scp  -v -r $from $to
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send $pass\n
}
}
interact
```

Comment: *Why* are you using `expect` for this at all? Showing your code would make this a more concrete, less vague question.

Comment: ...also, details matter -- if the script can use a FIFO rather than a concrete file as input, you might be able to not copy the file at all, and only stream it over the network.

Comment: ...if your question is "how do I copy a file over a network", for example, we already have plenty of Q&A entries showing that -- *without* use of `expect`.

Comment: If you want to always answer "yes" to questions from scp, tell it not to ask those questions in the first place; ie. `scp -o ScriptHostChecking=no`. If you want to pass a password, use `sshpass`, or -- much better -- use RSA key authentication. There's no point to `expect` here.

Comment: Arguably this is duplicative of [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)

Comment: Also note that questions about how to improve working code are generally not welcome here -- those are on topic at our sister site [codereview.se], subject to the detailed guidance at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, a StackOverflow question should revolve around a specific practical, answerable problem; "how can this be improved?" is not a problem.

Comment: Hello @CharlesDuffy,  I need to use 'expect' as I need to pass the password while doing scp.  As you can see in my question, I am doing "scp" twice (once from src to dest and then copying results from dest to source) and establishing "ssh" once to execute one script command, I am just checking if there is better way to do the same. I have added the code to copy the files.

Comment: You do not need `expect`. `sshpass` will pass in the password for you.

Comment: What kind of "better way" are you looking for, though? Do you just want to use a single authenticated transport for all three channels? You can do that -- see the ControlMaster/ControlSocket system, as documented at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing -- that way you only set up a single SSH connection (authenticating just once), and do all three operations over it.

Comment: My environment is RHEL and I am not supposed to install anything on it. I checked 'sshpass' but it is not available by deault.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok. You could consider to use sshfs to mount remote directory on src machine and use command like this file was on src machine.

example:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,nonempty user@10.1.2.3:/project /project
```