# Send file via SCP in R

Tags: r, scp

I would like to copy a file from my computer to a remote server via SCP using `R`.

I have found 2 functions that appear to satisfy this partially.

**1.**
Using `ssh.utils`

```
ssh.utils::cp.remote(path.src="~/myfile.txt",
                     remote.dest="username@remote",
                     remote.src="", path.dest="~/temp", verbose=TRUE)
```

I've noticed that with this method, if I need to enter a password (when remote doesn't have my public key), the function produces an error.

**2.**
Using `RCurl`:

RCurl appears to have more robust functionality in the `scp()` function, but, from what I can tell, it is only for copying a file from a remote to my local machine. I would like to do the opposite.

*Is there another way to use these functions or is there another function that would be able to copy a file from my local machine to a remote machine via SCP?*

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the function produces an error" for your method 1? I tried this method, was prompted to enter my password, and managed to copy the file successfully, so I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: The error I received was that the command exited with status 1. No further details and no password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to address the need to enter a password interactively is to use `sshpass` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955428/6455166) in a call to `system`, e.g.

```
system('sshpass -p "password" scp ~/myfile.txt username@remote.com:/some/remote/path')
```

See the linked answer above for more details, including options to avoid embedding the password in the command.

Comment: I'm actually seeking a method that permits the user to enter a password interactively.