# How to provide password in shellscript on linux server?

Tags: java

i have some query and scp command in a shellscript on linux server
and need to automate this shellscript 
how can i provide the database query password and scp password in the script only?
so that bash will not prompt for passwords

Comment: Give an example of what you tried already.

Comment: mysql -u user_id -p -h db_hostname db_name -e 'query' ;    scp  filename destination      using this in my shellscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to mySql without the password prompt by using `--password` for example,

```
mysql -u user_id --password='mypassword' -h db_hostname db_name -e 'query'
```

For scp see the answer posted here [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)