# what to do if i use shell_exec for a comand that require a password

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I have to use PHP to execute a shell command, in that case scp between 2 server, with shell_exec or exec.

```
$cmd="scp root@ip1:/dir/filename \ root@ip2:/dir/";
shell_exec(cmd);
```

When used in the shell, it asks me for the password to connect to the destination server.  How can I do this within PHP?  Where can I put the password?  And in the case of the command above, the passwords for servers ip1 and ip2.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use keys stored on file?

Comment: Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955428/133203).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)