# scp between two remote servers in Python

Tags: python, paramiko, scp

I am trying to connect a remote server using Paramiko and send some files to other remote server. I tried the code below, but it didn't work. I checked all connections, username and password parameters, they don't have any problem. Also the file which I want to transfer exist in first remote server in proper path.

The reason why I don't download files to my local computer and upload to second server is, connection speed between two remote servers is a lot faster.

Things that I tried:

- I set paramiko log level to debug, but couldn't find any useful information.
- I tried same `scp` command from first server to second server from command line, worked fine.
- I tried to log by `data = stdout.readlines()` after `stdin.flush()` line but that didn't log anything.

```
import paramiko
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect("10.10.10.10", 22, username='oracle', password='oracle', timeout=4)

stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command(
        "scp /home/oracle/myFile.txt oracle@10.10.10.20:/home/oracle/myFile.txt")

stdin.write('password\n')
stdin.flush()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a password to the standard input of OpenSSH `scp`.

Try it in a shell, it won't work either:

```bash
echo password | scp /home/oracle/myFile.txt oracle@10.10.10.20:/home/oracle/myFile.txt
```

OpenSSH tools (including `scp`) read the password from a terminal only.

You can emulate the terminal by setting `get_pty` parameter of [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command("scp ...", get_pty=True)
stdin.write('password\n')
stdin.flush()
```

Though enabling terminal emulation can bring you unwanted side effects.

A way better solution is to use a public key authentication. There also other workarounds. See [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50096/850848) (though they internally have to do something similar to `get_pty=True` anyway).

---

Other issues:

- You have to wait for the command to complete. Calling `s.close()` will likely terminate the transfer. Using `stdout.readlines()` will do in most cases. But it may hang, see [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).
- Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883).