# Send command after exec

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, expect, scp

I'm trying to a copy file from my raspberry pi to my computer with scp and automate it with expect.

My current sollution looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

exec scp pi@ip_address:/home/pic.jpg pic.jpg

expect "*assword: "
send "raspberry\r" # Password to raspberry pi
```

The first line works fine. However, the password does not get passed and I have to type it manually.

Would be thankful if somebody could help me!

Comment: I suggest to use public key authentication.

Comment: Alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp