# Insert a password after the command "scp" is being executed (Rust code implementation)

Tags: linux, rust, scp

I'm trying to write some sort of executable so I can easily upload a log.txt file from my server. I am using a "std::process::Command" and can't figure out how to combine commands between each other. I also can't figure out if it's correct to insert a password inside the next command. If I run this command in the terminal, next step it just asks me to input my password.
So here is the question. How can I combine theese two between each other?
If I run this command directly from terminal everything works fine.
Here is the code:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut donwloader = Command::new("scp")
        .args(["root@"some_ip":/root/admin/logs/logs.txt", "/Users/user/Desktop/"])
        .status()
        .unwrap();
    let password = Command::new("my_password").spawn().unwrap();
}
```

Debugger info :

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@91.222.238.129: Permission denied (publickey,password).
scp: Connection closed

I expected to combine theese two commands and to download a log file from my server.

Update : I don't know why my question was closed. They say this quetion has all answers : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp". I disagree, because there is a code just for terminal. While I'm searching for a Rust implementation, so it could be used inside the code there.

Comment: Ideally you should be using keys, not passwords.

Comment: And if you _do_ need to use passwords, you should use a native Rust client, not run the out-of-process `scp` executable.

Comment: That said, each `Command` you run is a _completely independent process_; running one command won't send input to a separate command. It _certainly_ won't send _that command's name_ as input to a previous command.

Comment: Even if you fix that and write the password to scp's stdin instead of running it as a second command, though, that still won't work: scp reads the password direct from the TTY, not from stdin, _specifically to make it hard for programs to fake data-entry from the user_. It's possible to fight that (as by wrapping `scp` in `sshpass`), but you _shouldn't_; the security measures are making it hard for a good reason.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I got you. Maybe it looks pretty stupid and not correct but for me is very important to find a way how to download files from there. E.g I want to launch the code and set an OpenVPN at the server and then download a generated config. I still need a way to complete this task. So I decided to figure out how to do it at this stage, when my task is compact & not overloaded with lots of code lines :)

Comment: I would probably use something like https://docs.rs/ssh2/latest/ssh2/struct.Sftp.html -- a native Rust client (and sftp, which is much better specified / more sanely designed than scp). Is there a specific reason your requirements include password authentication? (In an ideal world you wouldn't hardcode use of a key either but would let your user provide a SSH agent that knows how to get to an authorized key -- that way the agent can be doing something like reading a Yubikey or a smartcard or a TPM module to get the credentials to authenticate to your server)

Comment: (the really great thing about using a hardware token like a smartcard for SSH is that _malware can't copy it_; so you-the-human can walk around with a physical object that grants access to the servers and services you have a reason to use, and when you unplug it from a system, that system can no longer speak to those devices).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you compose these comments into an answer? particularly the Rust-native solution since otherwise the question is a dupe of [this](/q/50096/2189130) and [that](/q/1462284/2189130).

Comment: @kmdreko, I'm not the right person to write that Rust-centric answer; don't let me stop you from closing as duplicative. (I've poked at Rust's ssh2 for a project a while back, but ended up writing that project in Go using x/crypto/openssh).

Comment: Regarding your update: no, you're not. You're asking about how to run a linux command in the way the dupe describes under rust's control; that's **not** a rust specific problem.

Comment: @tink okay, how should I form my question so the question could be answered? Or where should I place it? I'm reading docs of ssh2 library and if we look at the answers in link which describes answers as you say - it can't be performed, because in ssh2 I have to create a tcpStream and then log in to server. Theese steps are pretty odd. So there is only solving for me - is to use std::process::Command library. And the question is about implementing that code through it.

Comment: @a____________, the duplicate tells you how to use sshpass. You already _know_ how to call commands from rust; if there's any reason you don't know how to call sshpass from rust, I'm pretty unclear on what that reason could be. (The example where it passes a password on a command line is horrifically bad security practice, but it _is_ using 100% only things you've clearly demonstrated that you already know how to do in Rust; and it's a pretty small step to pass the password to sshpass in the environment, which is less bad as environment variables are only readable by the same user account)

Comment: @a____________, ...anyhow, if you _do_ have a problem applying the linked duplicate, _demonstrate that problem_ by showing your attempt to use sshpass from rust and how it fails. sshpass successfully fixes the stdin-vs-tty problem I describe above; it's a lot _worse_ than using the ssh2 library from Rust (and I don't know why you think it's such a horrible thing to create a tcpStream &c in your Rust code), but while worse, it's workable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay, I'll add some other code samples in 12 hours. Also I've read docs for the Command and I have some thoughts. I'll try it tomorrow. If nothing works - I'll write here. And thanks for your attention to this problem. It's very kind from you